# How to avoid leaving a workbook open if error is found after its opening?

Tags: python, import-from-excel, xlwings

I have a piece of code that opens a workbook by means of the `xlwings` package and reads some stuff from it. When done, the workbook is closed. Sometimes, errors occur between the opening and the closing statements. This leaves the workbook open. When I attempt to run the code again, the file cannot be opened as it is already 'open'.

How can I deal with this?

Also, I cannot even open manually the workbook when this happens.

```
w1=app.books.open("WorkbookName.xlsx")
# Do stuff that can potentially give errors.
w1.close()
```

I expect to create some error handling so that if an exception is found along the way, the workbook is closed after it.

Comment: The python documentation for error handling is actually quite nice - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [try-finally](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) construct:

```
w1=app.books.open("WorkbookName.xlsx")
try:
    # Do stuff that can potentially give errors.
finally:
    w1.close()
```

A `finally` clause is always executed. If the code in the `try` clause raises an unhandled exception, then the python interpreter will jump to the `finally` clause and execute it (and terminate itself only afterwards).